# Difficulty in understanding how tex2Dlod works

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, textures, geometry-shader

I am new to shader programming. I was just referring to some blogs to learn more on this area. I came across this article https://halisavakis.com/my-take-on-shaders-grass-shader-part-i/

According to them, they are using a displacement texture to calculate the wind contribution

> **"We calculate the wind contribution by sampling a displacement
>   texture."**

```
       float4 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, midpoint);

         float2 windTex = tex2Dlod(_WindTexture, float4(worldPos.xz * 
    _WindTexture_ST.xy + _Time.y * _WindSpeed, 0.0, 0.0)).xy;

float2 wind = (windTex * 2.0 - 1.0) * _WindStrength;
```

The explanation for the code above is

> The sampling of the wind texture happens in lines 113-114 and it’s
>   pretty much the same method we’ve seen a bunch of times when it comes
>   to displacement textures: sample the texture, offset the UV’s (here
>   it’s the world position’s x and z components) by time and then map the
>   whole thing from -1 to 1 and multiply it by the strength of the
>   effect.

`midpoint` here represents midpoint of a triangle. 
As far as my understanding, in `mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, midpoint);` we are getting the world position of the midpoint

I dont really understand whats happening in

```
  float2 windTex = tex2Dlod(_WindTexture, float4(worldPos.xz * 
    _WindTexture_ST.xy + _Time.y * _WindSpeed, 0.0, 0.0)).xy;
```

and I dont really understand how .xz and .xy works! I searched everywhere and still couldnt get nice grasp over it!

Can someone explain? Thank you!

Comment: It's called [swizzling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-per-component-math). `worldPos.xz * 
    _WindTexture_ST.xy + _Time.y * _WindSpeed` is equivalent to `float2(worldPos.x, worldPos.z) * float2(_WindTexture_ST.x, _WindTexture_ST.y) + float2(_Time.y * _WindSpeed, _Time.y * _WindSpeed)`.

Comment: @Pluto Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea on tex2Dlod too?

Comment: You can look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-tex2dlod). The  `tex2Dlod(s, t)` samples `s` at uvs `t.xy` with mipmap LOD `t.w`. In that `float4(worldPos.xz * ...,0 ,0 )` t.w, the last component is 0.

Comment: Also tex2Dlod is used here instead of tex2D because it's on the vertex shader side, where no screen-space derivative of the coordinate is available to determine the mipmap level automatically